# Integrating a factorial expression

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate
$$ \int {1\over x(3+x^2)(\sqrt { 1-x^2})} dx$$

for solve this question we assume that:

$$\sqrt {1-x^2}=t$$ than: $1-t^2=x^2$. by this substitution the $x$ in factor $x(3+x^2)(\sqrt { 1-x^2})$ has difficulty.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

Hint first put $x^2=u $ and after that put ${1-u}=a^2$ that gets everything in denominator in $a^2$ and then use partial fractions to get some basic integrals

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find [Euler's way](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjE2bi43KjQAhWCSRoKHfd0ArMQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fplanetmath.org%2Feulerssubstitutionsforintegration&usg=AFQjCNH0hRan4mKTijLAtQN6jz_tFoc79Q&sig2=q6J5971oeXJU--UrhN_LTw&bvm=bv.138493631,d.d2s) for solving the integral interesting. Here the term $1-x^2$ has $\alpha=\pm1$ as roots (of $x^2-1=0$). So we can let $$\sqrt{1-x^2}=(x-1)t$$